# Binding Kendo DropDownList to a RESTFUL web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, kendo-ui

I have the following code for a Kendo Drop Downlist which binds to a REST end point

```
ddChange.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost/Project/MyMethod",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function () {
                return {
                    source: data.source,
                    c: data.c,
                    ch: data.ch,
                };
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return $.parseJSON(response);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    change: ddChange
});
```

Everything is seemingly working, except the end part. The call to `http://localhost/Project/MyMethod?source=1&c=2&ch=3` is occuring, I can see it happening and returning correct data, however, the `return $.parseJSON(response);` from `schema > data` is not so my drop down just contains many undefined entries because I am left with a string that still needs to be parsed to an array.

Doing this works for the Kendo Grid, should it work for the drop down list? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you parsing the response if its already in json?

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a string of JSON that gets parsed to an object. I'm probably misunderstanding something tough.

Comment: Can you share an example of your response data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema isn´t part of the transport object but a property of the datasource.

Can you try this?

```
ddChange.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost/Project/MyMethod",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function () {
                return {
                    source: data.source,
                    c: data.c,
                    ch: data.ch,
                };
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                return response;
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    change: ddChange
});
```

Or if your only doing that on the schema you could just omit it.